# Chrome not getting sourcemaps in Angular CLI Project

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, angular-cli

I'm trying to debug the typescript from my angular project (built with the CLI) in chrome developer tools.

- Chrome is aware that sourcemaps exists for my webpack bundles bc I get the 'Source Map Detected' message.
- There are no errors in the network tab, indicating a failed request for the source maps
- 'Enable Javascript Source Maps' is selected in chrome tools
- The contents of my wwwroot look like this:

  - inline.bundle.js
  - inline.bundle.js.map
  - polyfills.bundle.js
  - polyfilss.bundle.js.map
  - etc.
- inside my individual bundles, I have source map references to particular files (pre-bundled) as well as the final bundled source map (always the last line of the bundle).  For example:

  - sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
  - sourceMappingURL=shared.module.js.map
  - sourceMappingURL=main.bundle.js.map

Any ideas?

Also, if there's a better debugging strategy (e.g. using VSCode), let me know.  Based on a few searches, I thought debugging in chrome dev tools would be the least cumbersome, but perhaps I'm wrong.

Thx!!!!